# Handling common parts of exceptions together

Tags: c++, exception

I currently have some code I am trying to refactor. A large set of exceptions has some common code for all exceptions as well as some specific code which needs to be handled separately for each specific exception type. I am trying to figure out how to get rid of the common part in each `catch` block. One Idea is to do it like this:

```
try {
  /* Stuff that may fail */
} catch( const std::exception & ) {
  /* do common part here */
  try { throw; } 
  catch( const exception1 & ) {
    /* do stuff for exception1 here */
  }
  catch( const exception2 & ) {
    /* do stuff for exception2 here */
  }
}
```

However this strikes me as somewhat ugly.

Is there a better way to factor out this common logic, or is there actually a reason to avoid this attempt altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, `try`/`catch` should only appear sparsely in the code. The problem is that many times the actions done in a `catch` clause should also be done in case of early return, for example.

Idiomatic C++ uses RAII extensively to avoid situation where you need to cleanup in a `catch` clause, which generally removes most of the work.

Now, your pattern is not so bad *per se*, it does factor the common stuff. But this common stuff could perhaps be handled automatically.

In all the code bases I have stumbled upon, only a few times did I see a genuine use of `catch` clause, don't use it as a clutch.

Answer (score 3):

> A large set of exceptions has some common code

Move the common code into a function or method. Call the method from each `catch`. Just like eliminating any other duplication; the presence of a `try`..`catch` makes no difference.

But if you are *really* concerned about "a large set of exceptions", the real problem might be that you have a large set of exceptions. Why do different exceptions require different handling at all? Are exceptions really being used for only *exceptional* events?

Comment: This is very similar to what I have right now (in the code, not in the question). However this would mean I would have the call to this method in each exception and if somebody later adds an exception and forgets the call havoc will ensure. This bug might then go unnoticed for a long time, since the condition is, uhm, exceptional and thus will be handled very infrequently. Thus I am looking for a good way to keep this safer for later developers.

Comment: "if somebody later adds an exception and forgets the call" but that criticism applies to *any* scheme you use: a later programmer might incorrectly alter it. If the common code is abstracted into a function, it is very clear to a later programmer that the function should be called for every `catch`.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it possible to incorrectly alter any scheme. The question for me often is however, how easy it is to get something wrong. If you just can add additional exception cases as in other places with the code staying ok, this is hard to get wrong. If you have to figure out something special before you are able to add an exception people might and most likely will miss this. In one case you can only break stuff by actively changing something in the other case you mess up stuff by forgetting something. The second case is usually worse IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I would really just move the common code to a function.

Here is another idea:

```
try {
  /* Stuff that may fail */
} catch( const std::exception & e) {
  /* do common part here */  
  if (const exception1 * e1 = dynamic_cast<const exception1*>(&e) {
    /* do stuff for exception1 here */
  } else if (const exception2 * e2 = dynamic_cast<const exception2*>(&e) {
    /* do stuff for exception2 here */
  } else
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Neither of your solutions is very good coding practice. A lot of folks don't understand handling of exceptions so keep it simple. Your "special" handling is not going to be well understood and will probably not be maintained correctly.