# How to make exception code DRY?

Tags: c++, exception, dry, c++03

I am trying to debug my application by using exception catch-rethrows.  My exception handling code is longer than some of the blocks I am debugging, and it's all copy-pasted.

Is there a better way to repeatedly express the below code?  I suspect macros are the way to go here, but I usually avoid macros like the plague.

```
  try {
   // Code here...
  }
  catch (std::exception & e)
  {
    ErrorMsgLog::Log("Error", "std exception caught in " __func__ " " __FILE__ " " __LINE__, e.what());
    throw e;
  }
  catch (Exception & e)
  {
    ErrorMsgLog::Log("Error", "Builder exception caught in " __func__ " " __FILE__ " " __LINE__, e.Message);
    throw e;
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    ErrorMsgLog::Log("Error", "Unknown exception caught in " __func__ " " __FILE__ " " __LINE__);
    throw std::runtime_error ("Unknown Exception in " __func__ " " __FILE__ " " __LINE__);
  }
```

Comment: `forward` all the exceptions to a templated function ?

Comment: Make `Exception` a subtype of `std::exception`, just like any sane exception type is.

Comment: 1. This is not C++11.  Can't forward.
2. Exception is a Borland C++ Builder class.  Besides, even if I *only* handled std::exception, I'd still want to get away from the copy-pasting of it.

Comment: Since you're avoiding macros, may I suggest you envelop your entire application code in this `try catch` block? That way you'll just need to envelop the blocks of code that throw exceptions with a simple `try catch(...)` block that simply does `throw;` until it reaches the main `try catch` block.

Comment: Put it in a function that takes a callable object and runs it in the try block. Put all your code in said callable object (it could be a plain function) and pass it to the function.

Comment: Have you considered logging the exception when you *throw* it instead of when you catch it?  At least you could make `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` useful.  You are fibbing in your logged message btw, you didn't actually catch it.

Comment: There's a very clean solution to the problem you pose. Take a look at the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847279/code-reuse-in-exception-handling.

Comment: @R Sahu, no that's a solution to a different problem.  Voting to re-open.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: why that solution cannot be applied here?

Comment: Re-reading this now, I see two different ways to read this question.  One is like the one linked to by R Sahu, but the other is the repetition within the catch bodies, which isn't really addressed by the answers on the other question.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: the link offers a solution to avoid repeating multiple catch clauses with details by using a single `catch(...)`  with a call to a function. I fail to see how this is not a solution in this particular case. Or are you looking for a way to avoid catching at all? this would be a completely separate question, and yeah I think this particular example doesn't make a lot of sense to me: catching an exception to log something with info about catch site (not where it was thrown) and immediately rethrowing it, especially because this catch site can be in multiple different places.

Comment: But that function re-throws and has additional catches.  I've yet to see an answer that suggests ways to avoid the repetition within the catch bodies, whether it's logging or mapping exception types to error codes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling common parts of exceptions together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140383/handling-common-parts-of-exceptions-together)

Comment: I heard of some magicians who only catch exceptions they can handle. Therefore no rethrow needed nor extra logging.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this is probably using macros. The macro definition is a little bit ugly, but calling the macro will be pretty easy, and you will not need to re-organize your code. Here is a sample that shows how you could implement it:

```cpp
#define RUN_SAFE(code) try {\
    code\
  }\
  catch (std::exception & e)\
  {\
    ErrorMsgLog::Log("Error");\
    throw e;\
  }\
  catch (Exception & e)\
  {\
    ErrorMsgLog::Log("Error");\
    throw e;\
  }\
  catch (...)\
  {\
    ErrorMsgLog::Log("Error");\
    throw std::exception();\
  }\

int main(){
  RUN_SAFE(
    cout << "Hello World\n";
  )
}
```

If you are really adamant about not using macros, you could use the approach suggested by [@juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza) and use a higher-order function for the check that takes the code as a parameter. This approach will probably require you to refactor your code a bit though. Here is how you could implement it:

```cpp
void helloWorld(){
  cout << "Hello World\n";
}

void runSafe(void (*func)()){
  try {
      func();
    }
    catch (std::exception & e)
    {
      ErrorMsgLog::Log("Error");
      throw e;
    }
    catch (Exception & e)
    {
      ErrorMsgLog::Log("Error");
      throw e;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
      ErrorMsgLog::Log("Error");
      throw std::exception();
    }
}

int main(){
  runSafe(helloWorld);
}
```

Comment: Since you're using c++, use a `std::function` instead of a raw function pointer.  Use template arguments for the function argument type and return type.